# percentage difference between two group when one group contains only positive cases

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, proportion

I have two groups $i=1,2$, with different total cases $n_1$ and $n_2$ on which the number of positive cases is $x_1<n_1$ and $x_2=n_2$. So there is no variability in the second group. I wonder how I can formally test that the percentage in the two groups is different as I do not know if standard statistical testing works in such "borderline" cases. Also, I would like to know whether it were possible to practically implement the test in R.